# How do I continuously play an animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I have used a Lottie animation but that plays only one time I want it to play continuously. Do I use a for infinite loop?
How do I achieve this?

Here is the code:

```dart
GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        _animationController.forward();
      },
      child: Center(
        child: Lottie.asset('assets/animation_soundwave.json',
            repeat: true,
            controller: _animationController,
            onLoaded: (composition){
              _animationController
                  .duration=composition.duration;
            }
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: try with `_animationController.repeat()`

Answer (score 2):

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        
      },
      child: Center(
        child: Lottie.asset('assets/animation_soundwave.json',
            repeat: true,
            controller: _animationController,
            onLoaded: (composition){
             _animationController
                    ..duration = composition.duration
                    ..forward();
              _animationController.repeat();
            }
        ),
      ),
    ),
```